# How to create custom view ( c# win 8.1 -...)?

Tags: c#, windows

In Java, I use an `extends View` to create a custom `View`. How to do it on c#? 
You can either create an element using the `XAML` and associating the layout to any element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you need to create custom user control. Start with that empty xaml file and you can define your own layout, then fill the grid with other controls and etc. The code behind is in MyCustomControl.cs file.

```
<UserControl 
    Name="MyCustomControl"
    x:Class="MyCustomControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" >   

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind looks similar to this:

```
  public partial class MyCustomControl: UserControl
    {
        public MyCustomControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```